# codeigniter project migration from iis to apache2

Tags: apache, codeigniter, linux-mint

I have migrated my project from Windows IIS to Mint Apache2.
Unfortunately I am getting an error:

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.
```

I have changed permissions on the files to 755. Normally if there is a CI error (connecting to db etc) it throws an error.

I have opened my index.php with VI, and I have noticed ^M on the end of each line in EACH FILE. This doesn't show in Aptana though. 
[image: Strange endings on the end of each line]

I have spent last half a year writing this app and I'm not very excited about this.
Does anybody have any experience with this?

Thank you.

Comment: The ^M just really is the EOL, which gets annoying while your programming. But you'll need to give us more details from your error_log in order for us to help you further.

Comment: you can replace `^M` with `\r`

Comment: This makes sense now! I have checked the permissions of CI error folder, and it gives me only DEBUG messages. No errors as such.
Also I have checked log file under /var/log/apache2/error.log. There is nothing there as well. (apart from the missing favicon file- but I don't think that is the issue) Any suggestions where to look for some more information?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the shell on your server and it's running Linux/Unix, try this:

```
for i in `find . -type f` ; do dos2unix $i $i; done
```

The `` for i in `find . -type f` ; `` part finds all FILES within the current directory.

Then, `do dos2unix $i $i; done` runs `dos2unix` which will convert all your `^M`'s to the Unix standard which is just `\r`.

If you want to test it out on a single file, make a copy of a file and replace `find .` with `find filename.ext`

Comment: Thank you for this script. I run it, and it did modify the files, which is handy, although that still did not fix the website

Comment: You need to provide error logs then, because error 500 could be almost anything.

Comment: Right - I Have created a new ci project - That worked ok. So I have started manually copping file after file, setting after setting from my app to bare metal CI project. The answer was simple really. My PHP doesn't have an extension to work with mysql installed. I have updated php.ini file, but possibly apache doesn't have access to it. I'll get it sorted tomorrow. I'm quite surprised, that there were no errors at all in the logs :| Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's a very interesting issue. It might have been in the php error logs instead, if you have those set up in your Apache Virtualhost configuration for that site.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your php.ini.

```
display_errors = On
```

This should show a proper error instead of just throwing a 500. From therein it should be relatively simple to debug.